# How to call a method from inside a jQuery .click() and keep context?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have numerous "infoItem" elements which each have their own jQuery which manages them. Can anyone tell me why when I call "displayText()" that the elements inside that function are not the ones in the element which contains the click handler, but always the LAST element on the page?

[image]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="systemJavascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="infoItem">
            <div class="menu">
                <span class="menuOne">one</span>
                <span class="menuTwo">two</span>
            </div>
            <div class="content">intro message</div>
        </div>
        <div class="infoItem">
            <div class="menu">
                <span class="menuOne">eins</span>
                <span class="menuTwo">zwei</span>
            </div>
            <div class="content">Introtext</div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var INFOITEM = INFOITEM || {};

    INFOITEM.initialize = function(infoItem) {
        var elemMenuOne;
        var elemMenuTwo;
        var elemContent;

        this.defineVariables = function() {
            elemMenuOne = infoItem.find('.menuOne');
            elemMenuTwo = infoItem.find('.menuTwo');            
            elemContent = infoItem.find('.content');            
        }

        this.decorateElements = function() {
            elemMenuOne.css('background-color', 'beige');
            this.decorateAsLink(elemMenuOne);
            elemMenuTwo.css('background-color', 'beige');
            this.decorateAsLink(elemMenuTwo);
        }

        this.functionalizeElements = function() {
            that = this;
            elemMenuOne.click(function(e) {
                that.displayText('ONE');
            });
            elemMenuTwo.click(function(e) {
                that.displayText('TWO');
            });
        }

        this.displayText = function(text) {
            elemContent.html('you selected ' + text);
        }

        this.decorateAsLink = function(elem) {
            elem.css({
                'cursor' :'pointer',
                'text-decoration' : 'underline',
                'font-weight' : 'normal'
            });
        }

        this.defineVariables();
        this.decorateElements();
        this.functionalizeElements();
    }


    $('.infoItem').each(function(){
        INFOITEM.initialize($(this));
    });

</script>
```

Comment: When you call `INFOITEM.initialize`, you are setting `this.defineVariables` to a function.  Each time `initialize` is called, `defineVariables` is replaced with a new function.  So, after the `each` loop, `defineVariables` is a function bound to the last element.

Answer (score 3):

`INFOITEM` is a global variable so you are resetting this for every item in your page, so it's always pointing at the last element:

```
$('.infoItem').each(function(){
        INFOITEM.initialize($(this));
    });
```

You'd be better off rolling this into a Jquery pluin type structure and then binding it to one element and passing in the associated element.

Here's a bolierplate to get you started:

http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was to add an ID to each element, and in the click events, fetch that item again, which I can then pass to any method where I can manipulate it appropriately, instead of the internal variables.

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="systemJavascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="infoItem_123" class="infoItem">
            <div class="menu">
                <span class="menuOne">one</span>
                <span class="menuTwo">two</span>
            </div>
            <div class="content">intro message</div>
            <div class="contentOne">you clicked one</div>
            <div class="contentTwo">you clicked two</div>
        </div>
        <div id="infoItem_456" class="infoItem">
            <div class="menu">
                <span class="menuOne">eins</span>
                <span class="menuTwo">zwei</span>
            </div>
            <div class="content">Introtext</div>
            <div class="contentOne">du hast auf eins geklickt</div>
            <div class="contentTwo">du hast auf zwei geklickt</div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var INFOITEM = INFOITEM || {};

    INFOITEM.initialize = function(infoItem) {
        var elemMenuOne;
        var elemMenuTwo;
        var elemContent;
        var elemContentOne;
        var elemContentTwo;
        var itemId;

        this.defineVariables = function() {
            elemMenuOne = infoItem.find('.menuOne');
            elemMenuTwo = infoItem.find('.menuTwo');            
            elemContent = infoItem.find('.content');            
            elemContentOne = infoItem.find('.contentOne');            
            elemContentTwo = infoItem.find('.contentTwo');            
            itemId = infoItem.attr('id');
        }

        this.decorateElements = function() {
            elemMenuOne.css('background-color', 'beige');
            this.decorateAsLink(elemMenuOne);
            elemMenuTwo.css('background-color', 'beige');
            this.decorateAsLink(elemMenuTwo);
            elemContentOne.hide();
            elemContentTwo.hide();
        }

        this.functionalizeElements = function() {
            that = this;
            elemMenuOne.click(function(e) {
                that.displayText($('#'+itemId), elemContentOne.html());
            });
            elemMenuTwo.click(function(e) {
                that.displayText($('#'+itemId), elemContentTwo.html());
            });
        }

        this.displayText = function(clickedInfoItem, text) {
            clickedInfoItem.find('.content').html(text);
        }

        this.decorateAsLink = function(elem) {
            elem.css({
                'cursor' :'pointer',
                'text-decoration' : 'underline',
                'font-weight' : 'normal'
            });
        }

        this.defineVariables();
        this.decorateElements();
        this.functionalizeElements();
    }


    $('.infoItem').each(function(){
        INFOITEM.initialize($(this));
    });

</script>
```